# Android Chronometer: time format issue

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, chronometer

Why my chronometer wouldn't stop after I've told it to?

I have found out that it seems to be isolated to the tablet I have tested it on (7 inch `Galaxy Tab`). I have no idea why it would work on my phone yet not work on the tablet. The `Chronometer` is set up the same in both layouts (since I am using different layouts for the different screen sizes).

Here is how the `Chronometer` is handled in the class:

```
this.chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.calling_crono);

chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                String currentTime= chrono.getText().toString();
            if(currentTime.equals("00:20")) 
            {
              chrono.stop();
              Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            int end = -5;
            b.putInt("score", score);
            b.putInt("end", end);
            intent.putExtras(b); 
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
             }
            }
        });
        public void startCrono() {
 chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
 chrono.start();
}
```

Here is how it is set up in the normal-size screen:

```
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/calling_crono"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000099" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

And here it is in the large-size screen:

```
 <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/calling_crono"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#000099"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

The basic problem is that on the phone it works as normal, which is to move on after 20 seconds, but on the tablet it won't stop and keeps going ahead. Is there some reason why this works on my phone (`Xperia`), but not on the tablet. The only thing I can think off is the fact that they use different  `xml` layout files.

Comment: Why was this downvoted i'm asking a legit question why code is not working on one device over the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're experiencing isn't related to *"different layout xml files"*. It seems to be an Android **bug**, probably this one: [Chronometer in Android 4.2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41920).

To check that I've done a couple of tests (with only one layout) on a *normal screen size phone* (**`Android 4.2.2`**) and *Samsung Galaxy Tab 7* (**`Android 4.0.3`**). I get the following *string format* of the returned value of `chrono.getText().toString()`

1. **`Android 4.0.3:`** `"mm:ss"`
2. **`Android 4.2.2:`** `"m:ss"`

which corresponds to the reported *bug*.

Assuming that *your Galaxy Tab 7* has **`Android 4.2`** explains why *the Chronometer doesn't stop and keeps going ahead*: the condition `currentTime.equals("00:20")` is `false` because you compare two *strings of different format*, `"m:ss"` with `"mm:ss"`.

If my assumption is wrong and it does not regard to the `Android` version yet there is a solution to handle it.

**Solution:** I recommend formatting `currentTime` in a certain manner, e.g. `"mm:ss"` and then compare the formatted time with `"00:20"`. The following code snippet uses [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {

            String currentTime= chrono.getText().toString();
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").parse(currentTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String newTime = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(date);
            ...
```

Now do the comparison using `newTime`:

```
if(newTime.equals("00:20")) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: @Darren Murtagh In `onChronometerTick()`. See the editted version.

Comment: ok thank you i tested that and it and that solved the problem. you have been a great help as it would never have occurred to me that the android version would be a problem

Comment: i have accepted your answer and gave you the bounty. i cannot stress how much this helps